# Efficient way to create a symmetric matrix counting how often two strings belong to the same list

Tags: python, performance, matrix, networkx, coding-efficiency

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ID", "GROUP"])
df["ID"] = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"]
df["GROUP"] = [ ["g1", "g3"], ["g2", "g3", "g5"], ["g3", "g5"], ["g2"] , ["g1", "g5"], ["g3"]]
```

which gives:

```
df

      ID         GROUP
0     a1      [g1, g3]
1     a2  [g2, g3, g5]
2     a3      [g3, g5]
3     a4          [g2]
4     a5      [g1, g5]
5     a6          [g3]
```

and a list of groups as follows:

```
GROUPS = ["g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6"]
```

Here is what I would like to obtain:

```
groups_df

   g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6
g1  2  0  1  0  1  0
g2  0  2  1  0  1  0
g3  1  1  4  0  2  0
g4  0  0  0  0  0  0
g5  1  1  2  0  3  0
g6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

which counts the number of times two groups appear in the same list (or how many IDs are present in both groups).

My code looks something like this:

```
groups_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = GROUPS, index = GROUPS)

for group1 in GROUPS:

    for group2 in GROUPS:

        groups_df.loc[group1, group2] = df[(df.GROUP.map(set) & {group1}) & (df.GROUP.map(set) & {group2})].shape[0]
```

It works but it is very slow with my actual data which consists of about 200000 rows in `df` and about 760 different groups in `GROUPS`, and I guess my solution is not very clean.

The end goal is to use `groups_df` with `NetworkX`.

Can you think of a better way to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for reading this and for any help !

EDIT 1:

Following a suggestion from @gboffi (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477464/8115634), I ran the following:

```
data = np.array(df.GROUP)
items = GROUPS
sc = np.vectorize(list.__contains__)
t = sc(data[:, None], items)
groups_array = np.array([np.sum(t[t[:,i]], axis=0) for i in range(len(GROUPS))])
groups_df = pd.DataFrame(groups_array, columns = GROUPS, index = GROUPS)
```

It was incredibly faster on the actual data: only 33 seconds! Thank you very much for your help.

Still, I will gladly try other suggestions for comparison.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for how to improve working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this indirect way of solving your problem, that has the apparent benefit
of being `O(1)` in Python, because the other loops (that are necessary) are performed by Numpy

Let's start with some fake data (no dataframes, just `ndarray`s) in terms of a 10 row array of sets, of random length, containing integers from 0 to 4 inclusive

```
In [82]: import numpy as np
In [83]: import random
In [84]: items = np.arange(5)
In [85]: items
Out[85]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [86]: data = np.array([set(np.random.choice(items, random.randint(1, 5), False)) for _ in range(10)], dtype=set)
In [87]: data
Out[87]: array([{0, 2, 3}, {0, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1}], dtype=object)
```

Next, I transform this rather compact data into a boolean array

```
In [88]: sc = np.vectorize(set.__contains__)
In [89]: t = sc(data[:, None], items)
In [90]: t
Out[90]: 
array([[ True, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I understand that, if your data is sparse, this can be a significant additional memory requirement, but this simplifies the next step

```
In [91]: np.array([np.sum(t[t[:,i]], axis=0) for i in items])
Out[91]: 
array([[3, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 4, 3, 3],
       [2, 1, 3, 7, 5],
       [1, 1, 3, 5, 6]])
```

Here we sum the columns of `t` (corresponding to different items) choosing only the rows where an item is present.

Two remarks

1. I think this should be faster than two explicit loops in Python, but I have not a benchmark, at least for now...
2. I have tried to vectorize the last loop using broadcasting but to no avail, if someone, starting from my answer, is going to remove the last loop I'll be glad to upvote if they post an answer on their own.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with a very little bit of changes and it worked fine, so thank you very much for your help and for the explanation ! I will try other suggestions before running it on my full data, but as you will see it was already much faster with the example data.

Comment: It only took 33 seconds with the actual data, which is fantastic :) Again, thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I was lucky that you were willing to adapt my sketch of an answer to your specific needs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on simple hashmap counter:

```
counter = defaultdict(int)

for group in df['GROUP']:
    for i in xrange(len(group)):
        for j in xrange(i, len(group)):
            counter[(group[i], group[j]) if group[i] <= group[j] else (group[j], group[i])] += 1
```

And then you can convert this hashmap into your target dataframe:

```
data = {group: [counter.get((group, group2) if group <= group2 else (group2, group), 0) for group2 in GROUPS] for group in GROUPS}
groups_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=GROUPS)
```

But i'm sure there should be some elegant way to do it using pandas dataframe power.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! This is indeed much faster (0.0005 against my 0.1228 seconds on this example), but would you mind explaining how to convert this to the dataframe ? I am afraid my knowledge on this does not go beyond pd.DataFrame.from_dict(), which is unsurprisingly not working here...

Comment: @atonnerre I updated my answer with some example about converting dict into dataframe

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: It indeed worked fine, and including this last step it took 0.0020 seconds on the example. However I will keep @gboffi 's suggestion in the EDIT as it was twice faster. Still a very interesting solution, I learned something new, so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about with a combination of regex and filter on the dataframe values. Again! there may be some other optimized ways! Just one of, you may benchmark the snippet with your dataset.

```
for row, series in groups_df.iterrows():  
  for column,d in series.items():
    pattern = row if row == column else r'%s.*%s|%s.*%s' % (row, column, column, row)
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    groups_df[row][column] = len(filter(regex.search, df.GROUP.values))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! I tried your code and got this: "TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()", so I naively tried using

len(list(filter(regex.search, df.GROUP.values)))

and got "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".

Any idea?

Comment: I believe you are using Python3. Then len(list(filter(regex.search, df.GROUP.values))) should work. I've updated my answer to indicate regex pattern as raw string.Let me know whether it helps.

Comment: I am indeed using Python 3, however with list() and your updated code I unfortunately got the same error, "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Oh.. Thats sad!! Its working fine in my machine. By any chance you have groups with special characters pertaining to regular expression literals? I'm testing the snippet with the groups available in your question and its working. Real groups are different it seems. Anyhow I should have given the solution that is working! Let me try to run others approach and learn what is that missing in my solution!